# html wont load css for small screens

Tags: html, css, media

I have a problem, html wont load css for small screens. 
I have make other css loaded with no problems. Those that works have background image but one for small screens under 500px in width has not. It will have just background color. I tried to scale image to 500px and added as background image in small.css and it works but I don't wont it. 
Please help.
Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-        scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>PROCYCLING   |   MTB klub</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:801px) and   (max-width:1024px)" href="large.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:800px)" href="medium.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width:500px)" href="small.css" />
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS without background image:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Small Content Formatting */
body{
  color:#6fe123;
  line-height:1.5em;
  font-family: Myriad Pro, Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us small.css?

Comment: here it is without background image:

@charset "UTF-8";

/* Small Content Formatting */

body{
color:#6fe123;
line-height:1.5em;
font-family: Myriad Pro, Arial, Verdana;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: #2a2a2a;
}

Comment: I suggest you start by commenting out the viewport meta for testing, and resize your desktop browser window below 500px width - then take a look at the Chrome inspection window for that area. See if it's loading the image at all. Make sure to double check the image URL to see if it's correct (typo?), and maybe you're modifying the background position somehow? So far the code seems to be supposed to work

Comment: When I resize window it loads image from deafult.css document. Other two medium and large loads corresponding images with no problems.

Comment: And css documents are connected well, because when I add image to small.css it shows it on resize.

Comment: Try looking at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OhMrBigshot/J7ggr/) - it's working for me, but I added the `@media` parts at the CSS itself. Can you try see if it changes anything?

Comment: If the colors work but not the image, really the only thing I can think of is the position or the URL are wrong. I'm assuming there's no public link for me to see?

Comment: no, but I can send you email with source code. It loads image when I enable it. But I don't wont to have background image on page for small screens.

Comment: Then set it to `background-image: none`? Add ` !important` if it gets overridden by another file

Comment: Thanks! It is not showing the image now. Hope that I wont have much more problems with this site. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added the comment as an answer, please mark as accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the question backwards. I thought it's not showing an image when it should.
The problem was it was showing because of another CSS file and it's not supposed to be shown.

In such a case, it's good to explicitly tell CSS not to use a background image:

`background-image: none;`